# Case for Inner Classes in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the need for inner classes in Java. Author of this book I am reading, cites the following example -

> A particularly important use of inner classes is to make adapter
>   classes. An adapter class is a “helper” class that ties one class to
>   another in a very specific way. Using adapter classes, you can write
>   your classes more naturally, without having to anticipate every
>   conceivable user’s needs in advance. Instead, you provide adapter
>   classes that marry your class to a particular interface. As an
>   example, let’s say that we have an EmployeeList object:

```
 public class EmployeeList {
     private Employee [] employees = ... ;
     ...
 }
```

> EmployeeList holds information about a set of employees. Let’s say that we would like to have EmployeeList provide its elements via
>   an iterator. An iterator is a simple, standard interface to a sequence
>   of objects. The java.util.Iterator interface has several methods:

```
 public interface Iterator {
     boolean hasNext();
     Object next();
     void remove();
 }
```

> It lets us step through its elements, asking for the next one and testing to see if more remain. The iterator is a good candidate
>   for an adapter class because it is an interface that our EmployeeList
>   can’t readily implement itself. Why can’t the list implement the
>   iterator directly? **Because an iterator is a “one-way,” disposable view**
>   **of our data.** It isn’t intended to be reset and used again. It may also
>   **be necessary for there to be multiple iterators walking through the**
>   **list at different points.** We must, therefore, keep the iterator
>   implementation separate from the EmployeeList itself. This is crying
>   out for a simple class to provide the iterator capability. But what
>   should that class look like? Before we knew about inner classes, our
>   only recourse would have been to make a new “top-level” class. We
>   would probably feel obliged to call it EmployeeListIterator:
>       class EmployeeListIterator implements Iterator {
>           // lots of knowledge about EmployeeList
>           ...
>       } Here we have a comment representing the machinery that the EmployeeListIterator requires. Think for just a second about what
>   you’d have to do to implement that machinery. The resulting class
>   would be completely coupled to the EmployeeList and unusable in other
>   situations. Worse, in order to to function, it must have access to the
>   inner workings of EmployeeList. We would have to allow
>   EmployeeListIterator access to the private array in EmployeeList,
>   exposing this data more widely than it should be. This is less than
>   ideal.

Questions: 
1) I dont understand what the 'one-way' disposable view means in relation to why it makes the case for inner classes? Methods in the class EmployeeList should have been able to achieve this unidirectional navigation of the list, no?

2) Multiple iterators going through the same list object seemed to make a case for having iterator as a class, so I could instantiate it multiple times - HOWEVER, does this mean for one instance of class X below, I can instantiate multiple instances of class Y? If so, the class definition of X doesnt make it clear that it has MULTIPLE members of type (class Y) -

```
class X {

   int x1;
   class Y{ }

}
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Suppose the list provides that functionality directly. That means that when I start iterating, the list must initialize some state to remember where I am in the iteration (1st element, 2nd element, etc.). Then I decide to stop iterating. How does the list know that? How can it dispose this iteration state without me calling some `stopIterating()` method? Delegating to a separate object is much easier: if I stop iterating, I simply forget about the iterator maintaining the iteration state. The iterator goes out of scope and is garbage collected.
2. Yes, of course. Every time you call `list.iterator()`, you get back a new instance of the Iterator. Having an inner class `Inner` declared inside an outer class `Outer` doesn't mean that the outer class has a field of type Inner. It simply says that the Inner class instances, that must be created using the new operator, have access to the instance of the outer class. The outer class doesn't maintain any association with the inner class instances. That's basically the same thing as if the inner class was a top-level class, with a field of type Outer pointing the the outer class instance. The difference is that the inner class has access to all the private members of the outer class, which is not possible with a top-level class.

Comment: That makes sense - I am also trying to wrap my head around OOP in general - having done procedural programming for a while now (C, REXX, COBOL, PERL), the switch to doing things the OOP way is not the most intuitive.

Does this mean, the need to maintain 'state', should prompt considering the need for a separate class/type of its own? And in cases like these, where there is need for 'state' and 'access to inner workings' of another class, the need for an 'Inner Class'?

Thanks much!

Comment: Basically, yes. An object is behavior associated with state. The state os a list is its elements, in order. The state of an iterator is the list it iterates on, and the position of the next element in the iteration. The iterator thus has a reference to the list it iterates on, and some internal state (which depends on the kind of list) allowing to get the next element.

Answer (score 0):

> Methods in the class EmployeeList should have been able to achieve this unidirectional navigation of the list, no?

Assuming that you need the adapter to implement an interface, you could make your outer class implement the interface, but now your methods are not cleanly separated. You have some methods  dealing with the classes original intent, and some that are exclusive to the adapter. It gets even messier when your class implements multiple interfaces.

> HOWEVER, does this mean for one instance of class X below, I can instantiate multiple instances of class Y?

Yes, you can instantiate multiple instances of Y. The `class Y {}` in your code defines what it will look like, it doesn't represent an instance of `class Y` until you instantiate it - which you can do multiple times.

```
class X {

    private void myFunc() {
        Y y0 = new Y();
        Y y1 = new Y();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin - in this case, y0, and y1 created through myFunc will be linked to the SAME enclosing instance of X, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, it was in the instance of X where these instances of Y were created.